# Changing CSS border-width shifts button down

Tags: html, css, border

I have created an HTML button with a narrow border. When you click on the button, I change the width of the border. In the demo below, this change is highly exaggerated. On Google Chrome 84.0.4147.89 and Opera 70.0.3728.71, the changed border-width has the effect of moving the button downwards. On Firefox 79.0, the buttons stay where they are, which is what I expect.

```css
button {
  width: 30vmin;
  height:30vmin;
  border: 1vmin solid #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button:active {
  border-width: 10vmin;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0L549b7/)

Why is this happening on Chrome and Opera? How can I get the buttons to stay in their initial position on all browsers?

Comment: Why are you using vmin for the unit?

Comment: Interestingly, if you specify text or a pseudo-element for the button, there is no shifting down at least in my Chrome browser https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/qdpbsxLw/

Comment: @HoseinShendabadi `vmin` is not the issue. The effect is the same with `vh` or `px` or any unit other you choose. `30vmin` simply ensures that you will see the buttons full size inside whatever screen space you have.

Comment: you need to add vertical-align:top ... the issue is the baseline alignment

Answer (score 3):

I see the inspect elements in `chrome` and `Firefox` shows different in the `script`(JS) tag:

> 1. I see in Chrome the JS snippet is enabled however in firefox it is commented out.
> 2. `vmin` and `vmax` has different responses in different browsers, so you need to look into if you want to change that to `vh` and `vw`s.
> 3. I have tried my below code in both Chrome and Firefox.

however I was able to find a small hack for the issue which solves for all browsers with a a line of code, if it works for you then:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  border: 1vmin solid #888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button:active {
  border-width: 10vmin;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
```